# A word for a new type of exam

Tags: single-word-requests

In Saudi Arabia, the Ministry of Education has devised a new type of examination for those who flounder or stumble in some school subjects because of illness or family circumstances. My question is: Is there a specific name for such an examination? I have tried to figure out some names such as 'stumbling examination' and 'floundering examination', but I am not really sure if these terms are valid.

Comment: Hello, Mido. Naming requests are off-topic on ELU, but this seems a far more deserving cause than many. **Don't** use 'stumbling examination' or 'floundering examination': they sound ludicrous, and (worse) insulting.  Perhaps someone will check whether 'mitigationary' is listed in OED.

Comment: @Edwin: You're right.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth "mitigationary" is not (thank God) listed in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=%27mitigationary&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch).  When I search for this word, I am asked if I mean  •mitigation or
•mitigatory

Comment: How about a **second chance** exam.

Answer (score 2):

If a student misses an examination because of illness or family circumstances or because of another examination at the same time, and then takes the same or equivalent examination at a later date, this is commonly called a *make-up* examination.

For example, see [this information](http://soe.rutgers.edu/absence-exams) from the *Rutgers School of Engineering*:

> Students having an exam conflict should contact the instructor of the
>   course(s) involved for information regarding the arrangements for the
>   **make-up** examination.

If a student, on the other hand, has an acknowledged learning disability, then he or she takes the examination at the same time as the other students, but with adapted content or other accommodations such as extra time or a proctor reading the questions. The examinations for such students are commonly called *modified assessments* or *alternate assessments*.

For example, see [this information](https://www.centinela.k12.ca.us/apps/pages/index.jsp?uREC_ID=236406&type=d&pREC_ID=899182) from  *Centinela Valley Union High School District*, which uses the CMA:

> The California **Modified Assessment** (CMA) for Science is an assessment
>   for students in grades five, eight, and ten who have an individualized
>   education program (IEP) that designates they take the CMA for Science. ... The CMA for Science allows students with disabilities greater access to an assessment that helps measure how well they are achieving California’s content standards for science that were adopted by the SBE in 1998.

Comment: l really appreciate your answer. I know the term 'make-up exam', but l wasn't sure whether l could use it here.

Comment: +1  Make-up exam was the term used when I was at MIT (so naturally it is correct :)).

Answer (score 1):

**Remedial Examination** seems to fit the definition quite well, and is in common usage.

"**Remedial** : concerned with the correction of faulty study habits and the raising of a pupil's general competence"

But more generically, something is remedial if it is the remedy to a problem.

Comment: I appreciate your reply.

Comment: The term 'remedial exam' seems to have a different sense: a re-take for those who've failed the normal exam. I couldn't find any reference to those genuinely struggling through no fault of their own (this is a dissimilarity with the single word 'remedial). At any rate, attributed supporting evidence of any kind is missing here (and ait would need to address the two-word term not just the adjective).